# Firebase Android App keeps crashing after a certain time

Tags: java, android, firebase, exception, firebase-realtime-database

I have been coding in Android Studio using Firebase as my Database. The app works fine for a certain period of time, but crashes later on.

**PROJECT LEVEL GRADLE FILE**

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**APP LEVEL GRADLE FILE**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.admin.firstapp"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true

    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:28.0.0'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
    api 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.7.+'

    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'

    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.8.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.0.0'

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:17.1.5'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-storage:4.1.0'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:4.1.0'

    implementation 'com.github.jakebonk:NotifyMe:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.github.MAXDeliveryNG:slideview:1.1.0'

}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin.config.disableVersionCheck = true
```

**ERROR**

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: TokenRefresher
    Process: com.example.admin.firstapp, PID: 13467
    java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: No field PREFER_HIGHEST_OR_REMOTE_VERSION_NO_FORCE_STAGING of type Lcom/google/android/gms/dynamite/DynamiteModule$VersionPolicy; in class Lcom/google/android/gms/dynamite/DynamiteModule; or its superclasses (declaration of 'com.google.android.gms.dynamite.DynamiteModule' appears in /data/app/com.example.admin.firestapp-hfO7_xvBp7yTRBLG4jEOKg==/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk)
        at com.google.android.gms.flags.FlagValueProvider.initialize(Unknown Source:7)
        at com.google.android.gms.flags.FlagRegistry.initialize(Unknown Source:4)
        at com.google.firebase.auth.internal.zzx.initialize(Unknown Source:3)
        at com.google.firebase.auth.internal.zzt.run(Unknown Source:14)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:65)
E/UncaughtException: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: No field PREFER_HIGHEST_OR_REMOTE_VERSION_NO_FORCE_STAGING of type Lcom/google/android/gms/dynamite/DynamiteModule$VersionPolicy; in class Lcom/google/android/gms/dynamite/DynamiteModule; or its superclasses (declaration of 'com.google.android.gms.dynamite.DynamiteModule' appears in /data/app/com.example.admin.firstapp-hfO7_xvBp7yTRBLG4jEOKg==/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk)
        at com.google.android.gms.flags.FlagValueProvider.initialize(Unknown Source:7)
        at com.google.android.gms.flags.FlagRegistry.initialize(Unknown Source:4)
        at com.google.firebase.auth.internal.zzx.initialize(Unknown Source:3)
        at com.google.firebase.auth.internal.zzt.run(Unknown Source:14)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:65)
```

The app crashes after about 15/20 mins of inactivity. It doesn't go to fragments or activities which involve firebase.

**CODE THAT PRODUCES THE ERROR**

```
public class ViewBankProfile extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ImageButton editPic, cancel, confirmupdate;
    private EditText bankname, description, contact, website;
    private TextView bankusername;
    private DatabaseReference mDatabase;
    private String username;
    private Button update;
    private CircleImageView bankProfileImage;
    private static final int GalleryPicK = 1;
    private StorageReference bankProfileImageRef;
    private ProgressDialog loadingbar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_bank_profile);

        bankusername = findViewById(R.id.view_bank_user_name);
        bankname = findViewById(R.id.edit_bank_name);
        description = findViewById(R.id.edit_bio);
        website = findViewById(R.id.edit_website);
        contact = findViewById(R.id.edit_bank_contact_no);
        cancel = findViewById(R.id.cancel_edit_bank_profile);
        confirmupdate = findViewById(R.id.confirm_edit_bank_profile);
        update = findViewById(R.id.update_bank_profile);
        bankProfileImage = findViewById(R.id.view_profile_pic);
        editPic = findViewById(R.id.edit_profile_pic);
        bankProfileImageRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().child("Bank Images");
        loadingbar = new ProgressDialog(this);

        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("BankData", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        username = sharedPreferences.getString("UserName", "UserName");

        if (!username.equals("UserName")) {

            mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Banks").child(username);
        }

        Toolbar profileToolbar = findViewById(R.id.profile_toolbar);
        profileToolbar.setTitle("");
        setSupportActionBar(profileToolbar);

        editPic = findViewById(R.id.edit_profile_pic);

        bankProfileImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                intent.setType("image/*");
                startActivityForResult(intent,GalleryPicK);
            }
        });

        editPic.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                intent.setType("image/*");
                startActivityForResult(intent,GalleryPicK);
            }
        });

        update.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                updatebankprofile();
            }
        });

        confirmupdate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                updatebankprofile();
            }
        });

        cancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplication(), BankActivity.class);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        final SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("BankData", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        if (requestCode == GalleryPicK && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {

            CropImage.activity()
                    .setGuidelines(CropImageView.Guidelines.ON)
                    .setAspectRatio(1, 1)
                    .start(this);

        }

        if (requestCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) {
            final CropImage.ActivityResult result = CropImage.getActivityResult(data);
            if(resultCode==RESULT_OK)
            {
                loadingbar.setTitle("Uploading");
                loadingbar.setMessage("Please wait while your profile Image is Uploading...");
                loadingbar.show();
                final Uri resultUri = result.getUri();
                final StorageReference filepath = bankProfileImageRef.child(username + ".jpg");
                filepath.putFile(resultUri).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) {
                        if(task.isSuccessful()){
                            Toast.makeText(getApplication(),"Profile Image Uploaded",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            try {
                                Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), result.getUri());
                                String path = saveToInternalStorage(bitmap);
                                loadImageFromStorage(path);
                                SharedPreferences.Editor save = sharedPreferences.edit();
                                save.putString("Image",path);
                                save.apply();
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                            loadingbar.dismiss();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            String message = task.getException().toString();
                            Toast.makeText(getApplication(),"Error: "+message,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            loadingbar.dismiss();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("BankData", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        String name = sharedPreferences.getString("Name", "Name");
        String username = sharedPreferences.getString("UserName", "UserName");
        String con = sharedPreferences.getString("Contact", "Contact");
        String des = sharedPreferences.getString("Description", "Enter Information about the bank");
        String web = sharedPreferences.getString("Website", "Website");
        String path = sharedPreferences.getString("Image","N/A");

        if(!path.equals("N/A"))
        {
            loadImageFromStorage(path);
        }

        bankusername.setText(username);
        bankname.setText(name);
        description.setText(des);
        website.setText(web);
        contact.setText(con);

    }

    private void updatebankprofile() {

        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("BankData", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        String name = bankname.getText().toString().trim();
        String con = contact.getText().toString().trim();
        String des = description.getText().toString().trim();
        String web = website.getText().toString().trim();

        HashMap<String, Object> update = new HashMap<>();
        update.put("Name", name);
        update.put("Contact", con);
        update.put("Description", des);
        update.put("Website", web);
        mDatabase.updateChildren(update);

        SharedPreferences.Editor save = sharedPreferences.edit();

        save.putString("Name", name);
        save.putString("Description", des);
        save.putString("Contact", con);
        save.putString("Website",web);
        save.apply();

        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplication(), BankActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(intent);

    }

    private String saveToInternalStorage(Bitmap bitmap){
        ContextWrapper cw = new ContextWrapper(getApplicationContext());
        // path to /data/data/yourapp/app_data/imageDir
        File directory = cw.getDir("imageDir", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        // Create imageDir
        File mypath=new File(directory,"profile.jpg");

        FileOutputStream fos = null;
        try {
            fos = new FileOutputStream(mypath);
            // Use the compress method on the BitMap object to write image to the OutputStream
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                fos.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return directory.getAbsolutePath();
    }

    private void loadImageFromStorage(String path)
    {

        try {
            File f=new File(path, "profile.jpg");
            Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f));
            CircleImageView img=(CircleImageView) findViewById(R.id.view_profile_pic);
            img.setImageBitmap(b);
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplication(), BankActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

I have added one java code, however this error is produced wherever firebase Database is involved.

Comment: are you using flutter

Comment: `'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.1'` declared twice

Comment: No I ain't using flutter. Could flutter solve this problem? I've removed the double declaration of firebase auth now, will let you know if this solves it.

Comment: Removing twice declaration of firebaseauth did not Solve the issue.

Comment: Please add the code that produces this exception and please also responde with @AlexMamo

Comment: @AlexMamo I have added the code. However, error is produced everywhere firebase database is involved.

Comment: @AlexMamo can you please answer this?